# How to resize the button progmmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want Ui to be done programmatically ,i am using simple button,and it occupies the full width of screen,how should i be resizing the button width.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView label = new TextView(this);  
    label.setText("Hello");  
    label.setTextSize(20);  
    Button but = new Button(this);

    but.setText("Click Me");
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            System.out.println("Button Clicked");
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);  
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  

    ll.addView(label);
    ll.addView(but);
    setContentView(ll);  

}
```

Is there any separate layout to which i should be adding this button?Any tutorials regarding deeping understanding of layout programmatically will be useful.

Regards
Rakesh Shankar.P

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/resize-button-programmatically-using.html) for `Resize Button programmatically using Java Code`

```
                                   (or)

final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int heightDp = (int) (33 * scale + 0.5f);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = b.getLayoutParams();//b========>ur button
params.height = heightDp;
b.setLayoutParams(params);
b.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add params to button

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_l = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
but.setLayoutParams(rel_lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutParams params =new      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("login");
btn.setLayoutParams(params);

layout.addView(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this link for resize Button Programatically http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/resize-button-programmatically-using.html